# How to add IceServer to Univoice sample project in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I download UniVoice sample from github from this link:
https://github.com/adrenak/univoice

it's work fine with local network but not work in difference network , I searched and find out solution is add IceServer but I don't know how . my Iceserver like this :

```
const configuration = {
'iceServers': [{
urls: "stun:stun.relay.metered.ca:80",
},
{
urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80",
username: "*********",
credential: "*********",
},
{
urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp",
username: "*********",
credential: "*********",
},
{
urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443",
username: "*********",
credential: "*********",
},
{
urls: "turn:a.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp",
username: "*********",
credential: "*********",
} ]
};
const peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

how can add Iceserver to this part of project for init ChatRoomAgent :

```
 void InitializeAgent()
    {
        agent = new ChatroomAgent(
                  new UniVoiceAirPeerNetwork("ws://24.199.109.229:12776"),
               new UniVoiceUniMicInput(0, 16000, 100),
            new UniVoiceAudioSourceOutput.Factory()
        );
```

I Use AirSignal for Server side

Comment: what exactly doesnt work?  what is 24.199.109.229? is that your internal IP? what errors do you get. if its internal and you expect other networks are you sure there are no firewalls?